# android easy way to check contact has image

Tags: android, image, contacts

i am just using universal-image-loader to display contact images on listview. i just get photo uri like this.

```
public String getPhotoUri(String contactId) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,contactId);
    return uri + "";
}
```

and display in listview like this:

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(getPhotoUri(item.getContactId()), holder.ivHead);
```

it works well. but my question is when contact doesnot has a image. i will get error below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.utils.IoUtils.copyStream(IoUtils.java:69)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.BaseDiscCache.save(BaseDiscCache.java:109)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:273)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:229)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

it doesnot crash. and i can use showImageOnFail method on image-univeral-loader to display default image.but i hate the NPE . and when i scroll ,almost all the log is NPE.
so i just want to know how to check contact has image. i tried to use this way

```
    public String getPhotoUri(String contactId) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contactId));
    InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(mContext.getContentResolver(),uri);
    if (null !=is){
        return uri+"";
    }else {
        //TODO
    }
    return uri + "";
}
```

but ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream just do contact query on system contact database. so if i want display all the contact photo. it will query many times. so is there any good method to check contact has image?

Comment: u want to simply display an image through universal loading ? right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

 Retrieve image URI and check if it is NULL.

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
String image_uri = "";
```

Now get the image URI,

```
image_uri = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
if (image_uri != null) {  
  // set your image
} else {   // set default image
}
```

Method 2:
Try like this to retrieve contact photo:

```
public Uri getPhotoUri(int contactid) {
  Cursor photoCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'", null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
  photoCur.moveToPosition(contactid);
  Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, photoCur.getLong(photoCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
  Uri photo = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
  return photo;
}
```

Now use this to set image, (contactimage is an ImageView):

```
Uri contactphoto = getPhotoUri(contact_id);
contactimage.setImageURI(contactphoto);
if (contactimage.getDrawable() == null) {  // If no image is found.
   contactimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultImage);
}
```

Comment: @sunday did you find the ans useful?

Comment: i just using method 1 to know whether has a image . and use method 2 to get it. thanks